# How to draw an angle in flex using graphics tool

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How to draw angle in flex  There are tools for drawing rectangle,ellipse etc in flex
Didn't find anything to draw an angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean simple arcs you can use

```
graphics.curveTo()
```

method. Look :[Adobe help about drawing lines and curves.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html)

If you want something better look : [Here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/09/22/drawing-arcs-with-as3/)

And for Angles a modified version of Emanuele Feronoto's algorithm:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class angle extends Sprite {
    var my_canvas:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var deg_to_rad=0.0174532925;
    public function angle() {
        addChild(my_canvas);
        my_canvas.graphics.lineStyle(20,0xff0000,1);
        draw_angle(my_canvas,250,200,150,14,180);
    }
    public function
      draw_angle(movieclip,center_x,center_y,radius,angle_from,angle_to) {
        var angle=angle_from;
        var px=center_x+radius*Math.cos(angle*deg_to_rad);
        var py=center_y+radius*Math.sin(angle*deg_to_rad);
        movieclip.graphics.moveTo(center_x, center_y);
        movieclip.graphics.lineTo(px,py);
        angle=angle_to;
        px=center_x+radius*Math.cos(angle*deg_to_rad);
        py=center_y+radius*Math.sin(angle*deg_to_rad);
        movieclip.graphics.moveTo(center_x, center_y);
        movieclip.graphics.lineTo(px,py);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: these are drawing curves ... Exactly i want is angle ..like 30*,45*,50* etc

Comment: Ok  I added an angle drawing algorithm

Answer (score 0):

There are no any special tools for drawing angels in .graphics. You can make angle-drawing utility yourself, using standart graphics.lineTo(x,y) tool. If you'll concretize your goal, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is a bit unclear as angles are units of measure, so you can't in fact 'draw' them like you would with other graphical objects. That would be the same if I ask how to draw celsius degrees of temperature - i did search for that method but i can't find it. So  you either want 1. to draw 2 lines (or rays) forming an certain angle, or 2. draw an 'graphical' angle representation - that you can do with arcs like answered already. Furthermore, angles can be expressed in radians, degrees and grads, so you must decide what will be your preferred unit for inputing.